# Ошибка открытия терминала VS Сode

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code, powershell

Помогите запустить терминал.
В VS Code не открывается терминал. Дает следующую ошибку.

> Не удалось запустить команду процесса терминала
>   "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" (код
>   выхода: {2})

Приложил скрин, на нем указана консоль. Поменял на PowerShell, показывает тоже самое. В интернете лишь нашел о том что нужно поменять консоль на нужную, но у меня итак стоит нужная.

Справка о моей VS Code

```
Версия: 1.41.1 (system setup)
Фиксация: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Дата: 2019-12-18T14:58:56.166Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
ОС: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

[image: скрин беды]

Comment: @AlexFвсе существует, проверить. А зачем он оброщается к PS если стоит обычный cmd.exe?

Comment: https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2019/08/08/visual-studio-code-powershell/ возможно эта статья как-то поможет

Comment: `С:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` существует?

Comment: @VicTHOR да, существует

Comment: и settings.json указано `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "С:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"` ?

Comment: А вы Ad to PATH при установке включили? Сразу после установки проблема?

Comment: @АндрейКарчевский да, включил. Да, проблема сразу после установки.

Comment: @VicTHOR нет, там  cmd , но если поставлю ps будет тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Вы запускаете "`integrated`" терминал (горячая клавиша по умолчанию: `` Ctrl+` `` ) в то время как настройка задана (на скрине) для "`external`" терминала.

Для начала стоило бы проверить настройку "Explorer Kind" (на скрине установлена на "integrated").

Для изменения эмулятора консоли который будет запускаться внутри редактора необходимо изменить строку в файле настроек:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "С:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

Кроме того, как указано выше, каждую `\` (backslash) необходимо дублировать, это связано с парсингом настроек, а именно с использованием для этого регулярных выражений.

Предлагаю еще иной вариант:

Т.к. VS Code подтягивает терминал по умолчанию, можно сменить его. Или переназначить переменную `$SHELL`.

Детально: [Integrated Terminal in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows)